# How to make button as input type file

Tags: javascript, html, css, angularjs

I have a button. It should act as file upload on Button click.

```
<div id="Rectangle-541">
    <md-icon md-svg-src="./assets/images/csv.svg" class="ic_cloud_download_black_24px"></md-icon>
  <md-button class="Upload-CSV-from-mem">Upload .CSV From Memory</md-button>

</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out this

```js
var jimApp = angular.module("mainApp",  []);

jimApp.controller('mainCtrl', function($scope){
  
  $scope.fileChanged = function(){
        angular.element('#fileUplaod').trigger('click');
  };
  
  $scope.profilePictureSelected = function(data){
    console.log(data.files[0]);
  };
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>

<div ng-app="mainApp" ng-controller="mainCtrl">
  <div id="Rectangle-541">
      <md-icon md-svg-src="./assets/images/csv.svg" class="ic_cloud_download_black_24px"></md-icon>
      <md-button class="Upload-CSV-from-mem" ng-click="fileChanged()">Upload .CSV From Memory</md-button>
</div>

<input type="file" style="display:none" id="fileUplaod" ng-model="myFile" name='file' onchange="angular.element(this).scope().profilePictureSelected(this)" />
</div>
```

Comment: I tried this But getting error Looking up elements via selectors is not supported by jqLite! See: http://docs.angularjs.org/api/angular.element
http://errors.angularjs.org/1.5.5/jqLite/nosel

Comment: @TechnoGeek you need jquery for doing this

Comment: Yess I did It Working fine..Thankss Bro